# Pre-uploading pdf-files to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on an Android app that can show pdf files (with lectures). The files should be stored in the cloud, each user (student) should have access to them.

The idea is that users can't upload the files, they can only read them, so the files should be pre-uploaded. Is it possible to do in Cloud Firestore? I have searched a lot, but haven't found any opportunities to pre-upload files using computer and Firebase Console.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Firestore doesn't store PDF files.  It stores documents with fields and values.  Maybe you're thinking of Cloud Storage.

Comment: @Elijah You can upload files on Firebase Storage and get a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have commented, uploading files is best done to Cloud Storage which can also be access as part of Firebase.

To implement your scenario, you can upload the files through the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage/), and then set the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax) to determine who can access those files either to allow only reads, or to not even allow those and instead use [download URLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) to access them.